# Symfony 5 -> ERROR : Parameter "category" for route "default_article" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL

Tags: symfony

Hye,

I start to learn symfony and I have a problem after validating my form, the code is good, I am sure. Is it a problem of routing or requirements?
Can you help me, please!!
Thanks for your help !

Parameter "category" for route "default_article" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpu6S.jpg)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7264C.jpg)

[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPs5X.jpg)

[cmder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWxw2.jpg)

Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception
InvalidParameterException
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\InvalidParameterException: "Parameter "category" for route "default_article" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL."
C:\xampp\htdocs\actunews1\vendor\symfony\routing\Generator\UrlGenerator.php line 193

```html
if (!$optional || $important || !\array_key_exists($varName, $defaults) || (null !== $mergedParams[$varName] && (string) $mergedParams[$varName] !== (string) $defaults[$varName])) { // check requirement (while ignoring look-around patterns) if (null !==
$this->strictRequirements && !preg_match('#^'.preg_replace('/\(\?(?:=|<=|!|<!)((?:[^()\\\\]+|\\\\.|\((?1)\))*)\)/ ', ' ', $token[2]).'$#i '.(empty($token[4]) ? ' ' : 'u
  '), $mergedParams[$token[3]])) {                        if ($this->strictRequirements) {                            throw new InvalidParameterException(strtr($message, ['{parameter} ' => $varName, '{route} ' => $name, '{expected} ' => $token[2], '{given} ' => $mergedParams[$varName]]));                        }                        if ($this->logger) {                            $this->logger->error($message, ['parameter
  ' => $varName, 'route ' => $name, 'expected ' => $token[2], 'given ' => $mergedParams[$varName]]);                        }
```

[Application] Oct 24 13:38:07 |DEBUG  | SECURI Stored the security token in the session. key="_security_main"
[Web Server ] Oct 24 13:38:08 |ERROR  | SERVER POST (500) /article/creer-un-article host="127.0.0.1:8004" ip="::1" scheme="https"

```html
<?php


namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Entity\Post;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\SluggerInterface;

class PostController extends AbstractController

{

    /**
     * Formulaire permettant de créer un article
     * @Route("/article/creer-un-article", name="post_create", methods={"GET|POST"})
     */
    public function createPost(Request $request, SluggerInterface $slugger)
    {
        #1a. Création d'un nouveau Post
        $post = new Post();

        #1b. Attribution d'un user
        # FIXME Temporaire
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(User::class)
            ->find(1);

        $post->setUser( $user );

        #1c. Ajout de la date de rédaction
        $post->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());

        #2. Création d'un formulaire avec $post
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($post)

            #2a. Titre de l'article
            ->add('title', TextType::class)

            #2b. Categorie de l'article (Liste déroulante)
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Category::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ])

            #2c. Contenu de l'article
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class)

            #2d. Upload Image de l'article
            ->add('featuredImage', FileType::class)

            #2e. Bouton Submit de l'article
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)

            #2f. Permet de récupérer le formulaire généré
            ->getForm();

        #3.  Demande à Symfony de récupérer les infos dans la request.
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        #4. Vérifie si le formulaire est soumis et valide
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            #dump($request);
            #dd($post);

            # 4a. TODO Gestion Upload de l'image
            # faire un copier coller de la doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html
            # On remplace brochureFile par featureFile

            /** @var UploadedFile $featuredImage */# on remplace ts les brochureFile de la doc par featuredImage
            $featuredImage = $form->get('featuredImage')->getData();#on remplace brochure par featuredImage

            // this condition is needed because the 'brochure' field is not required
            // so the PDF file must be processed only when a file is uploaded
            if ($featuredImage) {
                $originalFilename = pathinfo($featuredImage->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                // this is needed to safely include the file name as part of the URL
                $safeFilename = $slugger->slug($originalFilename);
                $newFilename = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$featuredImage->guessExtension();

                // Move the file to the directory where brochures are stored
                try {
                    $featuredImage->move(
                        $this->getParameter('images_directory'),# on modifie brochure par images
                        $newFilename
                    );
                } catch (FileException $e) {
                    // ... handle exception if something happens during file upload
                }

                # On stocke dans la BDD le nom de l'image
                # On remplace product par post
                $post->setFeaturedImage($newFilename);
            }

            # 4b. Génération de l'alias
            $post->setAlias(
                $slugger->slug(
                    $post->getTitle()
                )
            );


            # 4c. Sauvegarde dans la BDD
            /*
             * Qu'est ce que le Entity Manager (em) ?
             * C'est une classe qui sait comment sauvegarder d'autres classes.
             */
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); # Récupération du EM
            $em->persist($post); # Demande pour sauvegarder en BDD $post
            $em->flush(); # On execute la demande

            # 4d. Notification / Confirmation
            $this->addFlash('notice', 'votre article est en ligne ! ');

            # 4e. Redirection
            return $this->redirectToRoute('default_article', [
                'category'=>$post->getCategory()->getAlias(),
                'alias'=> $post->getAlias(),
                'id'=>$post->getId()
            ]);

        }

        #5. Transmission du formulaire à la vue
        return $this->render('post/create.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the route definition and the way you use it. I would assume that, according to that error message, you haven't used any value for that `category` parameter

Comment: `$post->getCategory()->getAlias()` must be returning an empty string